# find all git commits for a file type

Tags: git, posh-git

its pretty simple to find all the commits containing a particular file.

```
git log -- .\Database\Tables\sometable.sql
```

but is there a simple way to find all the commits for a file type (recursively down child directories?) or will I need to write a script to do this?

(conceptually...)

```
git log -- .\Database\*.sql --recursive
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that perhaps you just need to escape the `*` so that it doesn't get expanded by the command line.  It would seem that you are on Windows so...  but I am on Linux and tested like so:

```
git init
mkdir -p blue/red/green
touch blue/red/green/colors
git add blue/red/green/colors
git commit -m "colors and dirs"
touch blackAndWhite
git add blackAndWhite
git commit -m 'b&w'
git log -- \*ors
```

The result on the last `git log` is:

```
commit 8fdb718b5b616dd495c00eb7a6d123c33f7707e5
Author: <snipped>
Date:   Sun Oct 14 19:49:43 2012 -0400

    colors and dirs
```

On the Windows escaping of `*`...  perhaps put it in either single or double quotes?  I'll add if I figure something out.

Comment: Just realized I do have my Windows laptop with Git here from work...  in a Git bash window my 'script' above works fine.  Perhaps your use of `\` as a path delimiter is just a slip-up?  Or you have some other Windows Git client than I do?

Comment: Yeah, using posh-git (powershell)

Comment: ok, so from the bash prompt it does work as I wanted. Must be a powershell thing like you suggest.

Comment: If you can figure out how to escape the `*` in the powershell so it doesn't expand it, it should work there as well.  I noticed that if the wildcards don't match anything in the current directory (Linux bash or Git bash) then they do get passed to `git log` and it does it's thing with them.  The escape is only really necessary if the wildcard does match something.

Comment: annoying that I can't figure out how to escape the * in PS, but at least I can do what I need from bash, that'll have to do for now...unless someone knows how to escape the * <hopeful/>

Comment: Looking around it may be the accent grave/backtick `.  Luck would have it that I'm not quite sure how to escape the backtick here on stackoverflow though.  http://serverfault.com/questions/47811/what-is-the-literal-escape-character-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see all contributions by type for all users in my repository. I found a Ruby package that will do this, `git fame` ([here](https://github.com/oleander/git-fame-rb)). If you type `git fame . --by-type` it will output something like this:

[image]